# How do you create a Shortcut to "Other Bookmarks" in Firefox?

Tags: vba, excel, firefox, shortcut, bookmarks

I want to make a macro in Excel 2010 that goes to "Other Bookmarks" in Firefox . . . I can't figure out how to do it

The closest I can get is, I open this "skin" / "chrome", and it default opens to "All Bookmarks" . . . `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -chrome chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul`

But, what I want is, which can only be done from within Firefox . . . I use this Keyboard Shortcut, and it default opens to "Other Bookmarks" . . . <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

What I've tried:

1.) VBA "Call Send Keys" from Excel 2010 does not "act on" Firefox

2.) AutoHotKey is not able to communicate with Firefox:  open FF, then input <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Is there an easy "switch" I can just add to the Shortcut "-chrome"? . . . like, -focus "Other Bookmarks" . . . This command doesn't work on the "places.xul" skin, so I can see what it's doing . . . <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>: View Source in Firefox

Or, is there a Firefox CLI, that I can use in a BAT file, and have another text file "act on" it, to open to "Other Bookmarks"?  Any idea where the commands to do so are provided?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  This VBA code gets the job done:

---

Sub Delete_Other_B(control As IRibbonControl)

' After being appended, delete the bookmarks from "Other Bookmarks"
'
' Set the Path variable equal to the Path of the program

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim Path As String

Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -chrome chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul"
x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)
```

' If I have the time at 1 second, sometimes that's too quick, and it pages down one screen within the spreadsheet
' The tilde meand "Enter"

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "{PGDN}~", False
```

' 12/18/17 Can you get to "Other Bookmarks" using Ctrl + Shift + B ?
' Yes, but it leaves a Firefox browser open

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I figured out.  There's too much to put here, so, I've put it on a 4-page PDF on my Google Docs:

4 Ways to get to Firefox "Other Bookmarks", from slowest to fastest
The following are 4 macros that I have in Excel 2010.
The first two just use VBA.
The second two use NirCmd.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eche0L-qHRWVA_yEh0JiL1k5SNK4HpCt

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Buttoncommander](http://www.buttoncommander.com/) 1.0 Software.

With this Tool you can make a set of Clickable Pictures on your Windows Desktop, any Picture can execute Autohotkey Macros Movements.

Watch this Youtube Video - How to make in 5 minutes a [Keyboard Shortcuts Launcher.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6t6LRY-tRs)

If you want to communicate true Two Programs( **excel 2010** and **FireFox Browser**) then this is the Right Software to do it.

Example:

1 - You can Make a Picture. (Search for Bookmarks)

2 - Choose that Picture and Then You can Write in the Command Editor from Buttoncommander this code.

Example 1 : [**Bookmark search**] Firefox

```
#notrayicon
; [+ = Shift]  [! = Alt]  [^ = Ctrl]  [# = Win]
send ^c ; copy the selected text(Bookmark Name) to clipboard memory
sleep 150
run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
WinWaitActive,Mozilla Firefox, , 2
sleep 150
send ^b ; open Bookmark search
sleep 250
send ^v ; paste the selected text in the bookmark search
sleep 150
send {enter} ;find Bookmark
;sleep 150
;send {Tab}
;sleep 150
;send {Space}
;sleep 150
;send {enter} ;go to Bookmark Url adress
```

Example 2 : [**Other Bookmark Search**] Firefox

```
#notrayicon
; [+ = Shift]  [! = Alt]  [^ = Ctrl]  [# = Win]
send ^c ; copy the selected text(Bookmark Name) to clipboard memory
sleep 150
run "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
WinWaitActive,Mozilla Firefox, , 2
sleep 150
send ^+b ; open Other Bookmark search
sleep 150
send {tab}
sleep 250
send ^v ; paste the selected text in the bookmark search
sleep 150
send {enter} ;find Bookmark
;sleep 150
;send {Tab}
;sleep 150
;send {Space}
;sleep 150
;send {enter} ;go to Bookmark Url adress
```

3 - Save and restart Buttoncommander now you are ready to go,

You can select any text In application Excel 2010 or any kind of applications, then Push that Picture on Your Desktop with your Mouse or Touch Device - and it will automatic do a Bookmark Search in the Firefox Browser.

Comment: AutoHotkey doesn't communicate with Firefox, so I suspect that Buttoncommander won't either . . . Are you "fluent" in using Buttoncommander? . . . Are you able to set a button (Ctrl+Shift+B) that "acts on" Firefox, and goes to "Other Bookmarks" in the places.xul "skin"? . . . Thank you for letting me know, I appreciate it (but I don't think it will work).

Comment: With communicate, i did mean that you can select any text/words in Exec 2010 and do automatic a [**Bookmark search in FireFox - Ctrl+b**] or do a[**Other Bookmark search in FireFox - Ctrl+Shift+b**] - and yes you are able to set a button (Ctrl+Shift+b) that "acts on" Firefox, i did make for you a extra example in the Answer i Hope you will like it. - With buttoncommander you can make Keyboard Shortcuts Macros with Autohotkey Scripts, that can do automatic for you the Computer Browser Search Movements.